# Running Clojure Code in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, clojure, liferay, portlet

I'm trying to run a portlet in a Liferay Container that runs Apache Tomcat 7.0.59.  The portlet refers to Clojure code in one of several fashions:

- 1) :gen-class :impl-ns  ( this namespace is aot compiled, the impl-ns namespace is not )
- 2) Clojure.var("clojure.core", "require").invoke(Clojure.read(ns)); then calling invoke on returned IFN ( ns is also a non aot compiled namespace )
- 3) ring uberwar ( this is not a portlet )

The one I am most concerned with is the first one, but in all cases, while the leiningen test all pass (and it's calling the code the portlet is calling) I get frequent but intermittent errors while either starting up tomcat with the portlet/servlet deployed or while doing a hot deploy.  The errors are symbol resolution errors in code I've unit tested and the unit test are passing:

```
  at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
        at portal_aot_common.CljJobManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 238 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: map->obj in this context
        at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:221)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:6940)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:6884)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:6845)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6427)
        ... 285 more
```

The code is not in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory or a jar in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory;  instead I opted to modify the `catalina.properties` file and include the src path in the `common.loader` property.  I've also tried using tomcat 7's virtualwebapploader virtualClasspath attribute.

The problem is that when it works, it works completely. But there always seems to be a 50/50 chance that it doesn't work and i get the above error.  The code is not in jar (I like being able to modify the code and restart the server without having to install or build anything).

For the ring uberwar, the problem seems to be that the servlet cannot find the handler class on tomcat startup, but seems to be ok when I build the war and do a hot deploy. `lein ring server` works fine, but actually deploying seems to have a 50/50 chance of success.

I'm using clojure 1.6.0 and java 8.

Any ideas on what might be happening would be appreciated.